Weighting imbalanced sample to reflect population distribution
I have a population (pop) with some characteristics (V1 ~ region, V2 ~ occupation type), all predictors are categorical. I have another dataset which includes only a part of population ~ 50% with an indicator variables (e.g. household income - continuous, property ownership - binary) . After linking 2 datasets, the final sample (sample) has a different distribution of intersection of V1 and V2 from population (d1, d2), so the aggregated statistics of sample and population on indicator variables differ . This is problematic for the analysis, so I need to somehow balance the sample to have the similar intersection of variables V1 and V2.
I was told that I should not remove data from the sample, but to assign weights to instances in the sample, but I do not know how to do it. Is there any good statistical method to do it?
Thanks for any help.
pop <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, list(sample(c("a", "b"), 
         replace = TRUE, size = 200, prob = c(0.5, 0.5) ), 
         sample(c("d", "e"), replace = TRUE, size = 200, 
                  prob = c(0.5, 0.5)), 
         sample(c("g", "h"), replace = TRUE, size = 200, 
                 prob = c(0.5, 0.5) )    ))

colnames(pop) <- c("V1", "V2")

sample <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, 
    list(sample(c("a", "b"), replace = TRUE, size = 100, 
                prob = c(0.7, 0.3) ), 
         sample(c("d", "e"), replace = TRUE, size = 100, 
                  prob = c(0.3, 0.7)), 
         sample(c("g", "h"), replace = TRUE, size = 100, 
                  prob = c(0.5, 0.5) )    ))

colnames(sample) <- c("V1", "V2")

d1 <- prop.table(table(paste0(pop$V1, pop$V2)))

d2 <- prop.table(table(paste0(sample$V1, sample$V2)))


If your sample units are part of your population, you want to estimate generalizability weights that make the sample resemble the population. These are analogous to estimating balancing weights for the ATE in the context of treatment effect estimation. The simple way to do this is to fit a model for sample membership given the variables you want to balance on (e.g., logistic regression), then use weights equal to the inverse of the predicted probability of being in the sample. This requires you to have the full population data available (with no missing values).
An alternative is to estimate balancing weights directly without a model; this is also known as matching adjusted indirect comparison (MAIC). Instead of fitting a model, we can estimate weights directly that match the moments (means) of the weighted sample to those in the population. Entropy balancing does this, but not all implementations make it so easy to simply supply the population moments and recover the weights. Another method is optimization-based weighting, which minimizes the variance of the weights subject to constraints on imbalance and specific moment targets.
To estimate weights manually with the full population available, you can run the following code in R:
fit <- glm(in_sample ~ V1 * V2, data = data, family = binomial)

weights <- 1 / fit$fitted[data$in_sample == 1]

For entropy balancing, if you have the full sample, you can run the following:
w.out <- WeightIt::weightit(in_sample ~ V1 * V2, data = data,
                            method = "ebal", estimand = "ATE")

weights <- w.out$weights[data$in_sample == 1]

You can also set method to be some other method of estimating weights; I believe with purely categorical predictors, any parametric or optimization-based method should yield equal weights. Using method = "glm" should be identical to using glm() as above.

Thank you. f I could ask for some more help, I calculated weights and I am not sure how to use them. I am trying to calculate % of house ownership in population, and % of people in quartiles of income in population, so the indicators available in linked data. Does this method make sense:

I don't understand the need to make this complex.  Since both V1 and V2 are measured in all datasets, adjusting for the effects of V1 and V2 on Y will give you meaningful conditional effects that do not require weighting (which increases variances of estimates).

Yes, this is what I thought so I will not be using the weights in the multivariate models. Part of the analysis is to estimate a percentage of property ownership (binary variable measured in sample) in population and percent of people in quartiles of income (continuous variable measured in sample) and this is where I want to use weights
